# LibGDX Camera rotation Issue

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to rotate my perspective camera around my model.  The model is at the centre (0,0,0) point.  This is my rotate camera method:

```
private void rotateCameraAroundModel() {
    camera.position.set(0,0,0);
    camera.position.rotate(Vector3.Y, 5);
    camera.position.add(0f, 0f, 200f);
    camera.up.set(Vector3.Y);
    camera.lookAt(0,0,0);
    camera.update();
}
```

I am trying to go to the centre, rotate by 5 degrees, then return to the same distance away.  However, the rotate doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out why, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm no expert in LibGDX; should `camera.position.rotate(Vector3.Y, 5);` be `camera.rotate(Vector3.Y, 5);`?  Also, the final `camera.lookAt(0,0,0);` replaces any direction your camera might be looking at up to that point.

Comment: @SteveSmith That did make the camera rotate, but now the model "looks like" it is rotating around the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out :)

```
private void rotateCameraAroundModel(float angle) {
    camera.position.set(centreX, centerY, centerZ);
    camera.rotate(Vector3.Y, (float) Math.toDegrees(angle)); // Rotate around Y axis by angle in degrees
    float x = (float) (centerX + radius * (Math.sin(totalPhi)));
    float z =  (float) (centerZ + radius * (Math.cos(totalPhi)));
    camera.position.add(x, 0f, z); //Move back out 2m using pythagorean theorem to calculate the position on the circle
    camera.up.set(Vector3.Y);
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
    camera.update();
}
```

So I needed to calculate the new position on the circle whilst rotating, which I did using some basic trigonometry